# Parallel processing for feature selection in microarray dataset

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, feature-selection, distributed, parallel

I want to apply feature selection on a dataset with some 30-40K columns and 100 rows ( ***total size: 400MB-800MB*** ). To decrease the time consumed for calculations involved (feature-feature), I want  to ***divide data in some 4-5 parts and execute all parts parallely.***
Since data is not huge in size, I am avoiding to use Hadoop.
What can be the ***option for this parallelization***.. ( multi-threading , GPU or anything else) ??

Comment: What do you want to do? I'm sure Bioconductor has multithreading functions for like gene counting. What're you trying to do?

Comment: i want to calculate mutual information (MI) between all possible pair of features for feature selection.